# Переменная сервиса не читается в методе запущенном в другом потоке

Tags: java, spring, асинхронность

Приложение на Spring
В сервисе крутится бесконечный цикл

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    public boolean isStart = false;

    @Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public void sending() {        
        while (isStartService) {
        ...
        }     
    }
}
```

В другом сервисе устанавливаю значение переменной isStartService = true.
Пока не было на этом методе аннотации Async все работало.
Но как только ее добавил, и он стал запускаться в отдельном потоке, то переменная isStartService  внутри этого метода теперь всегда = false. Цикл ни когда не выполняется.
Как мне правильно передавать значение этой переменой внутрь этого потока.
Т.е. вначале она должна быть true, а спустя какое-то время передается ее значение false и  тем самым метод прекращает свою работу.

Comment: А если volatile добавить? Или AtomicBoolean использовать?

Comment: Пробовал, volatile  не помогает. А с AtomicBoolean  ошибка вылетает, когда пытаюсь ей присвоить значение в другом сервисе: 
myService .isStart.set(isStart); 
Получаю ошибку "because "this.myService.isStart" is null" 
Хотя в конструкторе этого класса делаю ее инициализацию: 
isStart = new AtomicBoolean(false);

Comment: Сделайте поле у класса String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString(); и выведите id в лог в sending() до цикла, и в том месте где вы меняете значение. Чтобы проверить точно ли это один экземпляр. Плюс еще желательно код другого сервиса